# How to get standard deviation of grouped rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to calculate the standard deviation between page views on my site. I'd like to do this using pure MySQL - without querying the whole table to the webserver - and return a single number to the PHP code for further use. Each page view is stored as a `visitor_id` - `page_id` - `visit_count` trio as per the following schema:

```
 +============+=========+=============+
 | visitor_id | page_id | visit_count |
 +============+=========+=============+
 | 1          | 2       | 7           |
 +------------+---------+-------------+
 | 2          | 2       | 4           |
 +------------+---------+-------------+
 | 1          | 1       | 17          |
 +------------+---------+-------------+
 | 3          | 2       | 12          |
 +------------+---------+-------------+
 | 1          | 3       | 639478      |
 +------------+---------+-------------+
 | 2          | 1       | 6           |
 +------------+---------+-------------+
```

`page_id` refers to a PRIMARY_KEY in the pages table, `visitor_id` refers to a PRIMARY_KEY in the visitors table. The above table's primary key is the `visitor_id` - `page_id` pair, since the same page seen by the same visitor is recorded by increasing the `visit_count` of the corresponding row, instead of creating a new one.

Before calculating standard deviation, the entries should be grouped together by `page_id`, their `visit_count` summed (visitor_id can be ignored here), so, effectively, I want to calculate the deviation of the following:

```
 +=========+=============+
 | page_id | visit_count |
 +=========+=============+
 | 2       | 23          |
 +---------+-------------+
 | 1       | 23          |
 +---------+-------------+
 | 3       | 639478      |
 +---------+-------------+
```

I'm aware of the possible PHP solutions, but I'm interested in a *MySQL* one.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I meant **standard deviation**, as in mathematical statistics (dispersion, or variation from the mean).

Comment: "standard deviation" is very well understood.  But of what?  Over the pages with the summed counts or by visitor?  Sample data and desired results are highly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the standard deviation for each page (i.e., the visitors are the population):

```
select page_id, sum(visit_count) as visit_count, std(visit_count) as visit_std
from table1
group by page_id;
```

If you want the standard deviation over the pages:

```
select std(visit_count) as page_std
from (select page_id, sum(visit_count) as visit_count
      from table1
      group by page_id
     ) t;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, the one featuring the subquery is _exactly_ what I was looking for. If you have any recommendations on how to make the question more clear for future reference, please don't hesitate to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new table that stores timestamp + current views so you can view a history of changes in views. You'd be able to check the last two timestamped entries and how much the difference is between the two as well as a whole bunch of other stuff you haven't even thought of yet. Like graphs. Or pie charts showing activity increases per week day. Mmmm pie.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but that is done already, although in a much different manner.